# Обработка события по нажатию клавиши Enter

Tags: c#

Подскажите,что нужно добавить в данный код, чтобы действие происходило по нажатию клавиши <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
```

Answer (score 3):

**В WPF, элемент TextBox по умолчанию обрабатывает нажатие клавиши <kbd>ENTER</kbd> как переход к следующему элементу управления WPF** (аналогично нажатию <kbd>TAB</kbd> в открытом окне приложения).

**Свойство AcceptsReturn="True" элемента TextBox**, позволяет получить возможность обрабатывать событие нажатия <kbd>ENTER</kbd> при помощи KeyUp Event. Так же это свойство позволяет в элементе TextBox создавать новые строки. Новые строки не проблема, в тех случаях когда вам это нужно. Если вашей единственной целью является обработка события нажатия клавиши <kbd>ENTER</kbd> в элементе TextBox это свойство **не удобно**.

**Мой способ решения данной проблемы заключается в использовании пузырьковой стратегии.** Решение простое и короткое. **Для этого вы должны прикрепить обработчик события KeyUp к родительскому элементу (любому) объекта TextBox**:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TextBox_EnterButtomEvent.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextBox_EnterButtomEvent"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid KeyUp="Grid_KeyUp">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height ="0.3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Padding="0" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
        Input text end press ENTER:
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Padding="0" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
        You have entered:
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Name="txtBlock" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid></Window>
```

Логическая часть на C# (обратите внимание обработчик события нажатия клавиши ENTER прикреплен к элементу Grid:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Grid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            TextBox txtBox = e.Source as TextBox;
            if(txtBox != null)
            {
                this.txtBlock.Text = txtBox.Text;
                this.txtBlock.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

РЕЗУЛЬТАТ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]